# java Gradle copy only certain libs to folder

Tags: java, gradle

I have a java gradle application. And I have a task:

```
task copyDependenciesNoSr(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile into 'build/libs/nosr/lib'
}
```

But, I need to copy only certain libs from there in one task, and other set of libs in another task. How to filter it? I have over 50 dependencies libs, and I can't do 50 one-line-copy tasks and one big task for them. How to specify a list of jars from compile set to copy to folder?

Comment: I just answered your other question about finding dependency file location. Both these questions put together, it is clear you're trying to collect dependencies, don't reinvent the wheel, gradle application and distribution plugins already do this for you. Also, you should have posted a question about collecting/distributing dependencies instead of this. [See here](http://xyproblem.info/) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be able to help you out:

```
task copyDependenciesNoSr(type: Copy) {
    from (configurations.compile){
        include 'a','b'
        exclude 'x','y'
    }
    into 'build/libs/nosr/lib'
}
```

The commands also take patterns if you can specify any, in that case you won't have to specify the entire list.

For more information, look into https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html